# How does asp.net determine the name of compiled dll files from .cs files in a project?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am doing a code review of a web project and want to make sure I have all the compiled dll's. I was provided only three .dll files for static analysis but wonder if I am missing any because when I looked at the actual code base and project it contained 20 various .cs files.

All that I have opened shared a single namespace, but what was odd was the namespace was not the name of any of the .dll files.

How does .net compile the application in the dlls that are found in the /bin folder?
how does it get the names of the dlls?
how do namespaces fit into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dll does not have a one-to-one correspondence to a .cs file -- it represents all of the .cs files in a project (usually).  It's not unusual for 20 classes to be in a single assembly.

Get a copy of [.NET reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and look in the assembly and see if you see the namespaces and classes that you think should be there.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually the name of the project rather than  by namespace. You can have many namespaces in your DLL but none of them have to be the DLL name. It's usually just a convention to have to similar.

As far as I'm aware (but I might be wrong), ASP .NET looks at all the DLL files in the bin folder. The namespace/class information is within the DLLs